# dbSet Add - "No Duplicate Primary Key:" Field is NOT auto-incremented

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm updating to separate databases. They both connect no problems.

```
ModelY y = new ModelY();

y.the_name = x.Name;
y.timezone_id = x.TimeZoneId;


//First DB  
dbx.ModelX.Add(x);
dbx.SaveChanges();  // changes happen in db 


y.id = x.id; // grab the auto-incremented id

//Second DB
 dby.ModelY.Add(y);
 dby.SaveChanges();
```

So `x.id` is autoincremented BUT `y.id` is not autoincremented (want to keep it that way). No matter what `y.id` is I get this error as if somehow `y.id` becomes `0` before adding `y`

```
{"Message":"Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'}
```

Comment: Is there any relation between ModelX and ModelY ?

Comment: Just that they share some info in differently named fields

Comment: Also i can definitely see the value of y.id as being non-zero and unique when i capture the error with: catch (DbUpdateException e)
                {
                    dbContextTransaction.Rollback();

                    return BadRequest(e.GetBaseException().Message + "| tableY.id: " + tableY.id);

                }

Comment: What is the value of `x.id` after `dbx.SaveChanges()`? i.e. does EF know `ModelX` _does_ have a store-generated identity and updates it in the entity after saving accordingly?

Comment: x.id gets the auto-incremented value from the dbx , which i can check with a return

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha.. i just found this and it works - forcing the Key to accept the given value

```
public class ModelY
    {
        [Key]
        ***[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]***
        public int id { get; set; }
         .....
    }
```